# Unable to Execute Script files (.sql) in MySQL using DBeaver plugin, in Eclipse CDT with macOS Catalina (Shows, "No Active Connection")

Tags: mysql, dbeaver, macos

Unable to execute the script files (.sql).
It shows ***"No Active Connections"***.
But, test connection is complete, and localhosr has MySQL Icon with connection check mark, and I refreshed the projects.

I am using:

GUI: DBeaver: 21.0.1
Database: MySQL Community Server: 8.0.23.
IDE: Eclipse CDT 2020-12.
OS: macOS Catalina

Comment: did you try connctiong https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Connect-to-Database/

Comment: Thanks nbk: I did. I did everything once again. The error message still appears, but the database is created! it seems, it is a bug in Eclipse 2021-03..?

Comment: if you tested the connection with mysql client or dbbeaver , it seems more like a configuration problem, wrong parameters try the https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F